# Is it actually proven, that some Polynomials in the ulam spiral generate more primes than others?

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I know that there are some polynomials on the Ulam Spiral which generate more primes than others, like $f(n)=n^2+n+41$. But is it actually proven, that these polynomials generate more primes than others for infinitely many inputs?

Comment: How shall we compare this considering that it is assumed (not actually proven!) that polynomials satisfying some specific conditions produce infinite many primes ?

Comment: For what it is worth , it is hard to beat $n^2+n+41$ even in longer ranges as $[1,10^7]$. There are pretty sure "better" polynomials , but they probably have large coefficients. So , in this sense , $n^2+n+41$ is a "very good" polynomial.